# check status key value and print msg in the result

Tags: ansible

I would like to check status of uri if not equal to 201, then only would like print msg. I know I can do this just checking using when condition and print the msg. But I have multiple urls to be checked and if any of one url has failure status code, I need to print msg in rescue statement.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - block:
      - name: Check 201
        uri:
          url: https://google.com
          status_code: 201
        register: google_result
      - name: Check 201
        uri:
          url: https://google.com
          status_code: 201
        register: msn_result
      rescue:
        - debug: 
            msg: |
              {{ google_result|
                 selectattr('status', '!=', 201)|
                 map(attribute='msg')|list|default() }}
              {{ msn_result|
                 selectattr('status', '!=', 201)|
                 map(attribute='msg')|list |default() }}
```

I am receiving error like `"'str object' has no attribute 'status'"`. but if I check result variable type, it shows as `dict`.
I cannot put `msn.com` and `google.com` in loop. As per @Vladimir suggestion, I understand that I cannot run selectattr on dictionary.
I can achive using

```
{%- if google_result.Status != 201 %}
  {{ google_result.msg}}
{%- endif -%}
{%- if msn_result is defined and msn_result.status != 201 %}
  {{ msn_result.msg}}
{%- endif -%}"
```

Any better solution?

Answer (score 2):

The filter *selectattr* works with lists. The variable *result* is a dictionary. This is the reason for the error

> 'str object' has no attribute 'status'

Simply display the status and the message if you want to

```yaml
    - block:
        - uri:
            url: https://google.com
            status_code: 201
          register: result
      rescue:
        - debug:
            msg: |
              {{ result.status }}
              {{ result.msg }}
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: |-
    200
    Status code was 200 and not [201]: OK (unknown bytes)
```

---

Q: ***"I have multiple urls to be checked."***

A: Check them in a loop. For example,

```yaml
    - block:
        - uri:
            url: "{{ item }}"
            status_code: 201
          register: result
          loop:
            - https://google.com
            - https://google.com
      rescue:
        - debug:
            msg: "{{ result.results|selectattr('status', '!=', 201)|
                                    map(attribute='msg')|list }}"
```

When you check multiple urls the attribute *results* of the registered dictionary *result* will keep the list. Then the *debug* task will work as expected

```yaml
  msg:
  - 'Status code was 200 and not [201]: OK (unknown bytes)'
  - 'Status code was 200 and not [201]: OK (unknown bytes)'
```

---

Q: ***"I cannot put msn.com and google.com in loop."***

A: After a task fails the *block/rescue* construct ignores the rest of the tasks. Instead of *rescue*, ignore errors and *always* evaluate all registered variables.

```yaml
    - block:
        - uri:
            url: https://google.com
            status_code: 201
          register: google_result
        - uri:
            url: https://msn.com
            status_code: 201
          register: msn_result
      always:
        - debug:
            msg: |
              {% if google_result.status != 201 %}
              google.com: {{ google_result.msg}}
              {% endif %}
              {% if  msn_result.status != 201 %}
              msn.com: {{ msn_result.msg}}
              {% endif %}
      ignore_errors: true
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: |-
    google.com: Status code was 200 and not [201]: OK (unknown bytes)
    msn.com: Status code was 200 and not [201]: OK (33969 bytes)
```